# How do I return only select rows that meet user search condition

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a webpage (i am beginner php for only 1.5 months following book examples) that allows a user to enter a gpa and then search for students that meet the minimum entered. When the search button is clicked it calls a function from php file to query the database. My code is almost working right. The problem is it is returning all students and I want to return only the rows that meet minimum gpa entered. Tried to use HAVING clause and others but still doesn't return what I want. Thanks!

Link to sql fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/be9da

html:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function queryStudent() {
    var ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest;
    ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4 && ajaxRequest.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("ajax_output").innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;
        }
    };
    ajaxRequest.open("GET", "gpa_search.php", true);
    ajaxRequest.send(null);
}
</script>   
<form name="student">
<label>Minimum GPA: </label>
<input type="text" id="GPA" name="gpa"><br><br>

<input type="button"  onclick="queryStudent();" value="Search" id="button">
</form><br>
<!--output section after search-->
<section id="ajax_output">

</section><br><br>

<p>Students with higher than minimum GPA will be displayed here.</p><br>

<a href="search_split.htm">Search & Split</a>
```

php:

```
<?php
//get user input from text box on index.htm
$GPA = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'GPA');
//Code for query
$query = 'SELECT *
          FROM student
          ORDER BY studentID';
$statement = $db->prepare($query);
$statement->bindValue(':GPA', "%".$GPA."%", PDO::PARAM_STR); 
$statement->execute();
$students = $statement->fetchAll();
?>
<!--table to hold output-->
<table>
<tr>
<th>Student ID</th>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Email</th>
<th>GPA</th>
</tr>

<?php foreach ($students as $student) : ?> 
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $student['studentID']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $student['name']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $student['email']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $student['GPA']; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>

</table>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: None of the methods posted worked. Although it has to be the sql query something isn't working right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your code use the following:

```
 $query = 'SELECT *
      FROM student 
      WHERE GPA >= :GPA
      ORDER BY studentID';
 $statement->bindValue(':GPA', $GPA, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

This will search for students that have GPA greater and equal to `$GPA`, If you want to retrieve students that have only that GPA specifically then change `WHERE GPA = :GPA`

Comment: Is it possible to pass the value entered in the html text box to the query? That is the value that GPA should be compared to I believe. As it is the query is returning all students even if their GPA is lower than what was entered.

Comment: It will pass the value yes and it will be compared to the GPA in the database, is it returning everything for you?

Comment: Yes and I don't understand why. I'm passing the value entered by user intof the query

Comment: change `$GPA = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'GPA');` with `$GPA = $_GET['GPA'];`

Comment: The only reason i think of an error is that $GPA variable value is 0 and return everything; also try to `echo $GPA` to check that its value is not 0

Comment: @allendks45 is GPA column in your database a FLOAT, INTEGER or VARCHAR? If it is VARCHAR it wont (probably) be able to make a numeric comparison

Comment: The column is float data type.  I tried  the call method you have and I still get all rows.  Logic tells me it should return values in want

Comment: Was is the output of echo $GPA

Comment: I haven't tried echo and because I'm displaying a table it doesn't fit my parameters.

Comment: try the echo at least ONCE to make sure the $GPA is not null or empty

Answer (score 0):

Check your SQL query, the error is most likely from there. Your select statement doesn't have a `where` clause. It should be something like `select * from students where GPA = :GPA Order by studentid`